# What is this molten metal coming from the engine of an Avro RJ 100?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-maintenance

Yesterday I flew in an Swiss Avro RJ100. As soon as we landed I was shocked to see some sort of molten metal which was incandescent and glowing red dripping down from the vent as indicated in the picture. It was almost catching fire! I was suprised to see immediately the maintenance van pitch up to the plane when we didn't even get to a stop. Is this normal?

This image isn't of the problem flight, but shows where the problem was.

[image]

Comment: No its not normal. It sounds like an oil leak that burned thought the engine cover. They must have shut down the engine in flight, but unless you hear the engine fault like a compressor noise you wouldn't notice it was shut sown. --  link to incidents reagarding the RJ's -- http://www.aeroinside.com/incidents/type/rj1h/air-avroliner-rj-100

Comment: Interesting site! The plane is probably the same one that had the engine shutdown HB-IXR as it had that livery and it is the only RJ100 that has it in the fleet. Probably something is still wrong!

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni I don't know about Jul 2014, but two years later (Oct 2014) HB-IXR certainly isn't the only RJ100 in Swiss fleet. They have [HB-IYY](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32689/3230) as well, if not more.

Answer (score 4):

I do not see anything in your photo, apart the engine that looks perfectly normal.

Anyway
[here](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/ww2/projects/jet-airplanes/how.html) it is written that the fuel burns at up to 2000 degrees Celsius and the temperature at which metals in this part of the engine start to melt is 1300 degrees Celsius. Hence the metal may melt if something goes wrong.

Avro RJ100 has four engines so should be able to land with one inoperative. From the question [I have just asked myself](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/would-in-flight-engine-failure-of-the-passenger-jet-be-reported), it will not be qualified as accident so may not get widely known.

Comment: The picture is not one I took. I just checked on the internet to show where the problem was.

Comment: The incident most likely _will/did_ get reported. Date and flight number or aircraft registration would be need it to find it though as there are hundreds of incidents reported and published every day.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your photo, it seems the sun is shining roughly from your two o'clock.

What you saw may not have been metal, but simply some other fluid (fuel, lubricant, hydraulic) leaking out of the engine, reflecting the sunlight.

Comment: It's not actually his photo-- ps I guess that information wasn't obvious from the original post until a recent edit

Answer (score 0):

it seems that what you were looking is one of the reverse thrust latches that wasn't properly secured.