# What are these two tail elements of the Avro RJ100?

Tags: feature-identification, bae-146

What are these two tail-side elements of British Aerospace Avro RJ100 and what is their function:

[image]

Photo source: [Eric Verplanken, jetphotos.net](http://www.jetphotos.net/photo/8404128).

Comment: I am not sure the image (copyrighted) is compatible with the license of this site (CC-by-SA with attribution)

Comment: @DeltaLima Oops! Possibly. Though I don't have any other. Maybe we should brought usage of jetphotos.net photos discussion to meta?

Comment: I agree, good topic for meta. In fact, I found three related questions already: [This one on copyrighted images](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2900/19). Then [there](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1501/19) are [two](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2888/19) on proper image attribution.

Comment: @voretaq says best left as is.

Comment: @mins You have answered yourself! :> I forgot about this one. Thanks for reminding me this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The one behind is an aerobrake. The tail opens up to increase drag. It is much better seen in [this Wiki image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Eurowings_bae146-300_d-aewb_arp.jpg):

[image]

The one in front looks instead like the APU exhaust.

Comment: Just to expand a bit: ...and the reason to have an aerobrake is to allow for steeper descents. (It also has spoilers like most other airliners). BAe 146 was designed as a short takeoff/landing (STOL) aircraft to serve regional aerodromes in populated areas, and being able to descend (and climb) steeper is an important capability for it.

Comment: The one in front is the APU exhaust. As soon as I find the old SRM manual I have I'll add a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Airbrake and APU exhaust, just so.

Some aircraft use airbrakes on the tail cone, instead of airbrakes on the fuselage sides, the wings, or on the fuselage belly. The tail cone airbrake can easily be combined with a brake chute, should one be needed during testing.

Comment: what does this add w.r.t. the existing answer?

Comment: You should edit your answer to highlight what you add to existing answer.